# Bootstrap Date Picker - enable just all monday of every month

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date

I want to enable all monday of every month and disable past days. this is the code i'm using :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: new Date()
    });
});
```

and this is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hous9y5L/274/). this website has exactly what i want [example](http://www.staffordhouse.com/fees-calculator.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use daysOfWeekDisabled.  0-6 = Days of week

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: new Date(),
        daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,2,3,4,5,6"
    });
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hous9y5L/276/)

Comment: Note, that with date picker version 4.17.37 I had to use an array of weekdays for the option daysOfWeekDisabled: `daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,2,3,4,5,6]` worked perfectly fine. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the beforeShowDay method of the datepicker to restrict the available dates - it can also be used to restrict to certain weekdays.

Working example which only allows mondays in the future:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: new Date(),
         beforeShowDay:
            function(dt)
            {
            return dt.getDay() == 1;
          }
    });
});
```

Also updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hous9y5L/275/